# XSLT match attribute and apply css

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Im trying to match the attribute *audience="expert"* or *audience="novice"*

and apply it to the the html element as *class* attribute and as *audience* attribute.

xml:

```
<section audience="expert" xml:id="section-1">
    <title>Some Title</title>
    <para audience="novice">Lorem ipsum dolore amet</para>
</section>
```

my xslt template:

```
<xsl:template mode="main" match="section">
    <section class="d-inline-block">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </section>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@audience">
    <div>
        <xsl:attribute name="audience">
            <xsl:value-of select="@audience"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Expected output:

```
<div class="audience" audience="expert">
    Some Title
    <div class="audience" audience="novice">
       Lorem ipsum dolore amet
    </div>
</div>
```

But it will not match.

When i match for *para* it works but i will match section and para with one template with the attribute

```
<xsl:template match="para">
        <p>
            <xsl:if test="@audience">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">audience</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="audience">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@audience"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you show a bit more of your XSLT? For your template to be matched, there needs to be a template that selects that attribute beforehand (XSLT's built-in templates don't select attributes when matching an element). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your use of `<xsl:apply-templates/>`. This is shorthand for `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />` where `node()` selects elements, text nodes, comments and processing instructions. It does not select attributes.

You need to replace `<xsl:apply-templates/>` with this, so that it will then select the attributes

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
```

Also note that within the template matching `@audience` you should be doing `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="@audience"/>` as you arealready positioned on the audience attribute, so just want to get the current value.

```
<xsl:template match="@audience">
  <div>
    <xsl:attribute name="audience">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, better still, use Attribute Value Templates here

```
<xsl:template match="@audience">
  <div audience="{.}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```